# cqlengine Model __table_name__ is None

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cqlengine

I am trying the new cqlengine models as part of the datastax driver. , here I am not able get the **table_name** from the class

```
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class User(Model):
    uid         = columns.UUID(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4)
    fname       = columns.Text(primary_key=True,required=True)
    lname       = columns.Text(primary_key=True,required=True)
    user_id     = columns.Text(primary_key=True,required=True)
    email_id    = columns.Text(primary_key=True,required=True)
    password    = columns.Text(primary_key=True,required=True)
    salt        = columns.Text(required=True)
```

User.**table_name** gives me None.

Do I need to set this ?

### From the documentation

Model.**table_name**

Optional. Sets the name of the CQL table for this model. If left blank, the table name will be the name of the model, with it’s module name as it’s prefix. Manually defined table names are not inherited.

Answer (score 2):

As answered on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/python-driver-user/xhh8gD00oAM/sYGvBdX3CwAJ), considering the `__table_name__` can also be dynamically computed based on the name of the model, the way to get the table name is using `User.column_family_name(include_keypspace=False)`.

Comment: @Popescu, thanks. It works. But you have a typo on `include_keypspace`. It should be `include_keyspace`